# About Pointer alignment, is there a way to make a pointer aligned to some given memory boundary?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, alignment

What I want to do is **NOT** initilize a pointer that aligned to a given boundary, instead, it is like some function that can transform/copy the pointer (and the contents it is pointed to)'s phyiscal address to a aligned memory address back and forth, like `alignedPtr()` in the following code:

```
void func(double * x, int len)
{

//Change x's physical address to an aligned boundary and shift its data accordingly.
alignedPtr(x, len);


//do something...
};
```

Comment: That's only going to work if `x` points to some space sufficiently bigger than `len` to allow you to move things around.

Comment: It should work if the space is an elment larger than x (not considering the alignment's space requirements).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if the data is aligned in the virtual memory, it would also be aligned (at least up to 32bytes?) in the physical memory. Plus why would you move it back to where it was?

Comment: I don't think there's one thing to support that directly, no. You could use a combination of `alignof` or `alignas` with `std::copy` if you wanted to though.

Comment: I need more for optimal SIMD performance for some computing device like MIC etc.

Comment: why not just allocate it aligned...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the size of the allocated buffer is sufficiently large i.e. `len` + alignment required, the implementation would require 2 steps.

1. `newPtr = ((orgPtr + (ALIGNMENT - 1)) & ALIGN_MASK);` - This will generate the new pointer
2. Since the intended design is to have an inplace computation, copy from `newPtr + len` backwards to avoid overwrite of data.

Answer (score 2):

In C++11 you can use the slightly confusing to use [`std::align`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/align).

```
void* new_ptr = original_ptr;
std::size_t space_left = existing_space;
if(!std::align(desired_alignment, size_of_data, new_ptr, space_left)) {
    // not enough space; deal with it
}
// now new_ptr is properly aligned
// and space_left is the amount of space left after aligning

// ensure we have enough space left
assert(space_left >= size_of_data);

// now copy from original_ptr to new_ptr
// taking care for the overlapping ranges
std::memove(new_ptr, original_ptr, size_of_data);
```

Comment: And if you don't have C++11 yet, you can copy the implementation of `std::align` from libc++: http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/src/memory.cpp